# Counting frequency of multiple variables for each key in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I managed to merge two lists (one representing the key, the other one the values) in a dictionary, in order to further count the frequency of the values. That gives me a  a dictionary with multiples values in a list for each key :
[image]

I now want to count, for each key, the total number of DIFFERENT VALUES, for e.g. on my printscreen, for the key 1068, there are 2 different keys (70803, 70805).
I tried this:
[image]

However, it only gives me the TOTAL times the values appears,which is not what I want. 
As I am a very beginer in that, I have no idea how to proceed (especially with that dictionary with lists inside)

Thanks to all!

Loïc

Comment: put your code directly in your question, we can't copy-paste an image.

Comment: Please use [this tool](https://github.com/alexmojaki/askso) to help you write a clearer question.

Comment: It isn't clear what your expected result is.  Do you want to know the number of things in each *value* or the number of unique *things* in each value or the number of times a think *appears* in a value?  Please include an example input and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the following should do the trick:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    print(k, len(set(v)))
```

For each list of values you create a set of the elements and get its length.

Comment: Hi thanks! What I want to assess is to count, for each key, the number of different values it has! When I try your code, it returns me "unexpected EOF while parsing" . Maybe is it due to the dictionnary which contains lists inside (lists of values)?

Comment: You are probably reading data from a file but I can't help without seeing the code. The error message gives you the line where the program encountered a problem. This is useful information for debugging.

Comment: HI, thank you once again! I posted my code so you can clearly see it!

Answer (score 0):

here is my code:
first, the dictionnary I obtain from the two lists:

```
from collections import defaultdict
keys = ['31', '53', '57', '57', '57', '82', '82', '82', '82', '82', '82',         '82', '82', '82','82']
values = ['70803', '70901', '70801', '70801', '70801', '70801', '70804',  '70812', '70812', '70812', '70812', '70813', '70813', '70813', '70813']

d = {}
for k,v in zip(keys, values):
 d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
d
```

which return me:

```
 {'31': ['70803'],
'53': ['70901'],
'57': ['70801', '70801', '70801'],
'82': ['70801',
'70804',
'70812',
'70812',
'70812',
'70812',
'70813',
'70813',
'70813',
'70813']}
```

I then want to count for each key, the number of different values it has.
When I try to proceed:

```
from collections import Counter
from collections import defaultdict
d = {'31': ['70803'],
'53': ['70901'],
'57': ['70801', '70801', '70801'],
'82': ['70801',
'70804',
'70812',
'70812',
'70812',
'70812',
'70813',
'70813',
'70813',
'70813']}
for k, v in d.items():
   print(k, len(set(v))
```

It returns me:

```
File "<ipython-input-5-f243768fffa2>", line 248
print(k, len(set(v))
                    ^
```

SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

So here I am :) I don't know how to proceed further

Comment: It is still bothering me with the "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing "at the end!

Comment: Thank  you very  much for your  help. Everything's works  fine  now! Really  appreciate  it :)

Comment: You should not leave your code here. It belongs to your question. Mind the downvotes !